# Unable to invoke Compose Function in LiveData observer for Kotlin Fragment Class

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Live data from #SameViewModel , Used for Kotlin&Java Framents

@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a
@Composable function

[image]

For above I am inside setContent of ComposeView in onCreateView.
Problem I am facing is, I have multiple fragments using Java and Kotlin. I have to utilize LiveData for both type of Fragments.